# html How to show last character in limit width textbox

Tags: html, textbox, text-align

I want to show in text box as "/11/02"  BUT now it show as "2016/"

```
.date {
        width: 40px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-align-last: end;
    }

<input id="date" name="date" class="date" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="2016/11/02">
```

[capture textbox with width 40px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfSNa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery for this.

```
<script>
    var date = $(".date").val();
    var last = date.substr(date.length - 6); 
    $(".date").val(last);
</script>
```